# Add constraints to UITextView change contentOffset

Tags: ios8, uitextview, uistoryboard, autolayout

I have set constraints to the text view as on image below:

[image]

But as you can see on the simulator the contentOffset is different for text view under ARTIST NAME label. Seems like text view tries to show text from the bottom then from top at first:

[image]

I want to try to resolve this issue without any code, but I have added this method that scrolls text view back to the top:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.theTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
}
```

When I debug code and print out text view before line `[self.theTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO]` the contentOffset of text view is **0, 144.5**:

```
(lldb) po self.theTextView
<UITextView: 0x7d26ac00; frame = (3 423; 153 90); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bbbdf30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bbbd540>; contentOffset: {0, 144.5}; contentSize: {153, 243}>
```

After `[self.theTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO]` contentOffset is **0, 0**:

```
(lldb) po self.theTextView
<UITextView: 0x7d26ac00; frame = (3 423; 153 90); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bbbdf30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bbbd540>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {153, 243}>
```

But I can figure out why constraints bring some issues with content offset. And why at start text is shifted. Without any constraints text view displays "Lorem ipsum" as a first line, but with constraint it shows "nulla pariatur..." as you can see on image above as full visible line the line above is cut off at all.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolved it ? I set setContentOffset of textview to 0,0 but does not make an difference. Please let me know if you have resolved this issue.

Comment: @iOS hey man, it's an old issue for me, so I had some trick to make it work, but it was working in strange way for me. As you know UITextView is a UIScrollView child. So you can use all needed method to scroll content to the top as you did for scroll view when you need to scroll it up. As I remember I've created UITextView instance and in viewDidLoad I scrolled up my text view programatically. But honestly maybe there is some another beautiful solution to avoid this text shifting issue.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I just resolved it :)

Comment: @iOS yae, no problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In layoutSubviews if UIView and in viewDidLayoutSubview ad the below line:

`[textview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];`

This worked for me.